# Is it possible to prevent `useLazyQuery` queries from being re-fetched on component state change / re-render?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-hooks, react-apollo, apollo-client

Currently I have a `useLazyQuery` hook which is fired on a button press (part of a search form).

The hook behaves normally, and is only fired when the button is pressed. However, once I've fired it once, it's then fired every time the component re-renders (usually due to state changes).

So if I search once, then edit the search fields, the results appear immediately, and I don't have to click on the search button again.

Not the UI I want, and it causes an error if you delete the search text entirely (as it's trying to search with `null` as the variable), is there any way to prevent the `useLazyQuery` from being refetched on re-render?

This can be worked around using `useQuery` dependent on a 'searching' state which gets toggled on when I click on the button. However I'd rather see if I can avoid adding complexity to the component.

```js
const AddCardSidebar = props => {
  const [searching, toggleSearching] = useState(false);
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useState({
    name: ''
  });
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCard, setSelectedCard] = useState();

  const [searchCardsQuery, searchCardsQueryResponse] = useLazyQuery(SEARCH_CARDS, {
    variables: { searchParams },
    onCompleted() {
      setSearchResults(searchCardsQueryResponse.data.searchCards.cards);
    }
  });

  ...

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>AddCardSidebar</h1>
      <div>
        {searchResults.length !== 0 &&
          searchResults.map(result => {
            return (
              <img
                key={result.scryfall_id}
                src={result.image_uris.small}
                alt={result.name}
                onClick={() => setSelectedCard(result.scryfall_id)}
              />
            );
          })}
      </div>
      <form>

        ...

        <button type='button' onClick={() => searchCardsQuery()}>
          Search
        </button>
      </form>

      ...

    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Even I am getting this problem. What I am trying to do is useLazyQuery during the component mounting
````useEffect(() => refetchFunction(), [])````
But whenever my state changes, the refetchFunction is called again (INTERNALLY SOMEWHERE)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `react-apollo` documentation doesn't mention whether `useLazyQuery` should continue to fire the query when variables change, however they do suggest using the `useApolloClient` hook when you want to manually fire a query. They [have an example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries/#manually-firing-a-query) which matches this use case (clicking a button fires the query).

```
function DelayedQuery() {
  const [dog, setDog] = useState(null);
  const client = useApolloClient();

  return (
    <div>
      {dog && <img src={dog.displayImage} />}
      <button
        onClick={async () => {
          const { data } = await client.query({
            query: GET_DOG_PHOTO,
            variables: { breed: 'bulldog' },
          });
          setDog(data.dog);
        }}
      >
        Click me!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This solution perfectly resolved the issue I had with useLazyQuery which keeps firing requests on rerendering. Thank you

Answer (score 43):

You don't have to use `async` with the apollo client (you can, it works). But if you want to use `useLazyQuery` you just have to pass variables on the `onClick` and not directly on the useLazyQuery call.

With the above example, the solution would be:

```
function DelayedQuery() {
  const [dog, setDog] = useState(null);
  const [getDogPhoto] = useLazyQuery(GET_DOG_PHOTO, {
    onCompleted: data => setDog(data.dog)
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {dog && <img src={dog.displayImage} />}
      <button
        onClick={() => getDogPhoto({ variables: { breed: 'bulldog' }})}
      >
        Click me!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In my opinion this should be the accepted answer, since is using the useLazyQuery hook.

Comment: How would you get back the error and loading states of the lazy query?

Comment: @AndrewEinhorn - with `const [getDogPhoto, {data, loading, error}] = useLazyQuery(GET_DOG_PHOTO...`

Comment: This works! useLazyQuery not getting fired again on component load/re-render.

Thanks @Yann Pravo

Comment: This helped a lot! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When using `useLazyQuery`, you can set `nextFetchPolicy` to `"standby"`. This will prevent the query from firing again after the first fetch. For example, I'm using the hook inside of a Cart Context to fetch the cart from an E-Commerce Backend on initial load. After that, all the updates come from mutations of the cart.

Answer (score 1):

The Apollo Client documentation isn't explicit about this, but useLazyQuery, like useQuery, fetches from the cache first. If there is no change between queries, it will not refetch using a network call. In order to make a network call each time, you can change the `fetchPolicy` to `network-only` or `cache-and-network` depending on your use case ([documentation link to the fetchPolicy options](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#supported-fetch-policies)). So with a fetchPolicy change of `network-only` in your example, it'd look like this:

```
const AddCardSidebar = props => {
    const [searching, toggleSearching] = useState(false);
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useState({
         name: ''
    });
    const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
    const [selectedCard, setSelectedCard] = useState();

    const [searchCardsQuery, searchCardsQueryResponse] = 
        useLazyQuery(SEARCH_CARDS, {
            variables: { searchParams },
            fetchPolicy: 'network-only', //<-- only makes network requests
            onCompleted() {
            setSearchResults(searchCardsQueryResponse.data.searchCards.cards);
        }
    });
  ...

  return (
      <div>
      <h1>AddCardSidebar</h1>
      <div>
        {searchResults.length !== 0 &&
          searchResults.map(result => {
            return (
              <img
                key={result.scryfall_id}
                src={result.image_uris.small}
                alt={result.name}
                onClick={() => setSelectedCard(result.scryfall_id)}
              />
            );
        })}
      </div>
      <form>

        ...

        <button type='button' onClick={() => searchCardsQuery()}>
        Search
        </button>
      </form>

      ...

    </div>
  );
};
```