# Fetch graphql query result on render and re-renders BUT LAZILY

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a React Apollo app and what I am trying to do is that I have a component that renders some data using charts. For this data, I have some filters that I save in the local state of the component (Using hooks)

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState(defaultFilters);
```

Now what I want is that whenever the component mounts, fetch the data using the default filters. But I also want to re-fetch data when the user updates the filters **AND CLICKS ON SUBMIT** and I'd fetch the results using new filters.

Since I also want to fetch the results on filter update, I am using useLazyQuery hook provided by apollo

```
const [getData, {data}] = useLazyQuery(GET_DATA_QUERY, { variables: {filters} });

useEffect(getData, []); // this useEffect runs only when the component mounts and never again
```

But, what happens is whenever my state, *filters*, updates the getData function is automatically run! ALWAYS! (BEHIND THE SCENE)

1. How do I handle such cases, where I want to fetch results on mounting and re-rendering.
   I have tried using *useQuery and refetch provided by it* but I get the same problem there, whenever I update the state, the component rerenders and the useQuery hooks is run and makes the call. (That's how I believe it runs)
2. How do I fix my current code. Calling the getData function inside the useEffect function makes it run on every re-render.

I think I the problem defined in this [stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57499553/is-it-possible-to-prevent-uselazyquery-queries-from-being-re-fetched-on-compon) is somewhat similar to mine.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that you really have two different states that you're trying to utilize a single hook for. You have state that represents your inputs' values in the UI, and then you have state that represents the filters you want to actually apply to your charts. These are two separate bits of state.

The simplest solution is to just do something like this:

```
const [inputFilters, setInputFilters] = useState(defaultFilters)
const [appliedFilters, setAppliedFilters] = useState(inputFilters)
const { data } = useQuery(GET_DATA_QUERY, { variables: { filters: appliedFilters } })

const handleSubmit = () => setAppliedFilters(inputFilters)
const handleSomeInputChange = event => setInputFilters(...)
```

This way, you use `inputFilters/setInputFilters` only to manage your inputs' state. When the user clicks your submit button, the `appliedFilters` are set to whatever the `inputFilters` are at the time, and your query will update to reflect the new variables.

Comment: Okay, so basically, when I update inputFilters, the component re-renders and the useQuery hook is NOT RUN because the inputFilters state is not used in it. Is it so?

Comment: Okay, thanks. One more question, what exactly is controlling this part? Like if I create a function inside this functional component and pass it the appliedFilters like so
````const [inputFilters, setInputFilters] = useState(defaultFilters)
const [appliedFilters, setAppliedFilters] = useState(inputFilters)
const { data } = useQuery(GET_DATA_QUERY, { variables: { filters: appliedFilters } })


const tempFun = (appliedFilters) => {
console.log("TEMP FUN RUN");
}````

this tempFun always run but useQuery hook doesn't. So is it useQuery managing to run query on appliedFilters update?

Comment: Also, there seems to be 1 problem with this approach, if the user clicks on submit again, just to refresh the data, without changing the filters, the query won't fetch new results!! :\

Comment: `useQuery` is always called on render, but internally it doesn't make another request unless the options change or you've set the `fetchPolicy` to, for example, `network-only`.

Comment: If you want to send a request every time submit is clicked, you can compare `inputFilters` to `appliedFilters` and if they are equal, instead of calling `setAppliedFilters`, call `refetch`. `refetch` is returned by the `useQuery` hook and can be called to manually trigger a refetch of your query.